# undefined reference to nlopt

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use `sudo apt-get install libnlopt-dev` to install nlopt lib. when i `catkin_make` in my pc, report says like bellow, like can't link the lib. i donot know how to fix the problem.

this is the report.

```
alex@ubuntu:~/planner_examples_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/alex/planner_examples_ws
Source space: /home/alex/planner_examples_ws/src
Build space: /home/alex/planner_examples_ws/build
Devel space: /home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel
Install space: /home/alex/planner_examples_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/build"
####
[  0%] [  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] [  0%] Built target _gridmapping_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_GridObstacleUpdate
Built target _gridmapping_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_GridPoint
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  1%] Built target circular_curve_lib
[  4%] Built target alglib
[  4%] Built target gdal_utils
[  6%] Built target math_utils
[  6%] Built target boostrand1
[  6%] Built target random_points1
[  7%] Built target stupidrand1
[  7%] Built target rosparam_util_getvector
[  7%] Built target std_msgs_util
[ 12%] Built target sbpl
[ 12%] Built target nav_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 12%] Built target _tictoc_profiler_generate_messages_check_deps_ProfilerEntry
[ 12%] Built target _ca_nav_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_PathXYZVPsi
[ 12%] Built target _ca_nav_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_PathXYZ
[ 12%] Built target _ca_nav_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_XYZVPsi
[ 12%] Built target _ca_nav_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_XYZVViewPoint
[ 39%] Built target ompl
[ 39%] Built target _ca_nav_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_PathXYZVViewPoint
[ 39%] Built target nav_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 39%] Built target nav_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 39%] Built target _ca_nav_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_LookAheadTime
[ 44%] Built target mesh_loader_3ds
[ 44%] Built target _ca_nav_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_WorkspaceTrajectory
[ 44%] Built target pcl_util_examples
[ 45%] Built target pcl_util_pc2_iterator_examples
[ 45%] Built target pcl_util_rgb
[ 45%] Built target scrollgrid_examples
[ 45%] Built target tf_utils
[ 45%] Built target _shapes_generate_messages_check_deps_PolygonDepth
[ 45%] Built target _shapes_generate_messages_check_deps_Point2D
[ 45%] Built target _speed_profile_generate_messages_check_deps_SpeedProfile
[ 45%] Built target _shapes_generate_messages_check_deps_PolygonWithHolesDepth
[ 45%] Built target gridmapping_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 46%] Built target gridmapping_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 47%] Built target gridmapping_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 48%] Built target alglib_minqp_d_bc1
[ 48%] [ 48%] Built target alglib_example_df
Built target circular_curve_lib_example_dubins_path_set
[ 51%] [ 51%] Built target gdal_utils_example_dem
Built target circular_curve_lib_example_trochoid
[ 51%] Built target ompl_GeometricCarPlanning
[ 51%] Built target math_utils_scratch
[ 52%] Built target ompl_HybridSystemPlanning
[ 52%] [ 52%] Built target ompl_HypercubeBenchmark
Built target ompl_KinematicChainBenchmark
[ 52%] Built target ompl_OptimalPlanning
[ 53%] Built target ompl_PlannerData
[ 53%] [ 53%] Built target ompl_PlannerProgressProperties
[ 53%] Built target ompl_RigidBodyPlanning
Built target ompl_Point2DPlanning
[ 54%] [ 54%] Built target ompl_RigidBodyPlanningWithControls
[ 54%] Built target ompl_RigidBodyPlanningWithIK
Built target ompl_RigidBodyPlanningWithIntegrationAndControls
[ 54%] Built target ompl_RigidBodyPlanningWithODESolverAndControls
[ 55%] [ 55%] [ 55%] Built target ompl_StateSampling
Built target test_adjacency_list
Built target ompl_state_example
[ 55%] Built target test_sbpl
[ 55%] Built target tictoc_profiler_generate_messages_cpp
[ 55%] [ 55%] [ 56%] Built target tictoc_profiler_generate_messages_py
Built target std_msgs_util_load_pose
Built target tictoc_profiler_generate_messages_lisp
[ 58%] [ 60%] Built target ca_nav_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Built target ca_nav_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 62%] Built target ca_nav_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 63%] Built target mesh_loader_3ds_example
[ 64%] Built target shapes_generate_messages_cpp
[ 65%] Built target shapes_generate_messages_py
[ 66%] Built target shapes_generate_messages_lisp
[ 67%] Built target tf_utils_transform_vector
[ 67%] Built target speed_profile_generate_messages_cpp
[ 67%] [ 68%] Built target speed_profile_generate_messages_lisp
Built target speed_profile_generate_messages_py
[ 68%] Built target gridmapping_msgs_generate_messages
[ 68%] Built target tictoc_profiler
[ 68%] [ 68%] Built target tictoc_profiler_generate_messages
Built target ca_nav_msgs_generate_messages
[ 68%] Built target shapes_generate_messages
[ 68%] [ 68%] Built target speed_profile_generate_messages
Built target tictoc_profiler_example
[ 68%] Built target ca_nav_msgs_trajectory_converter
[ 68%] Built target ca_nav_msgs_trajectory_converter_example
[ 68%] Built target distancemap2
[ 72%] Built target shapes
[ 73%] Built target distancemap2_3d_obst_test
[ 73%] Built target shapes_cgal_complement
[ 73%] Built target distancemap2_subscribe_to_grid
[ 73%] Built target shapes_bbox_shape_example
[ 74%] Built target shapes_cgal_connect_holes
[ 74%] Built target shapes_cgal_difference
[ 74%] Built target shapes_cgal_multiple_holes
[ 74%] Built target shapes_cgal_nested_triangulation
[ 74%] [ 75%] Built target shapes_cgal_polygon_join_intersect
Built target shapes_cgal_polygon_intersection
[ 75%] Built target shapes_draw_shape
[ 75%] Built target shapes_in_shape_example
[ 75%] Built target shapes_load_sample_polydepth_set
[ 75%] Built target shapes_polygon_difference_example
[ 76%] Built target shapes_sample_in_shape
[ 77%] Built target environment_generator
[ 79%] [ 82%] [ 82%] Built target environment_generator_example_poisson_forest
Built target environment_generator_example_environment_serialization
Built target planning_common
[ 82%] Built target environment_generator_example_poisson_forest_cylinders
[ 83%] Built target environment_generator_example_read_binvox
[ 83%] Built target environment_generator_example_random_corridor
[ 83%] Built target environment_generator_example_superposition
[ 83%] Built target environment_generator_example_read_cuboid_set
[ 83%] Built target planning_common_example_constraints_enforcement
[ 83%] [ 84%] Built target planning_common_example_path_waypoint
Built target planning_common_example_path_utils
[ 84%] Built target planning_common_example_simple_grid
[ 84%] Built target planning_common_example_task_space_dubins
[ 84%] Built target planning_common_example_smoothness_objective
[ 84%] [ 85%] Built target planning_common_example_time_scaling
Built target planning_common_example_speed_warping
[ 86%] [ 86%] Built target planning_common_example_workspace_checking
Built target planning_common_example_world_velocity
[ 86%] Built target chomp
[ 86%] Built target common_representation_interface
[ 87%] Built target sampling_planners
[ 89%] Built target curvature_constrained_state_spaces
[ 91%] Built target speed_profile
[ 92%] Built target sbpl_common
[ 92%] Built target yagsbpl_ompl
Linking CXX executable /home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/curvature_constrained_state_spaces/curvature_constrained_state_spaces_example_bvp_solver
Linking CXX executable /home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/curvature_constrained_state_spaces/curvature_constrained_state_spaces_example_clothoid_path
Linking CXX executable /home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/curvature_constrained_state_spaces/curvature_constrained_state_spaces_example_distance
Linking CXX executable /home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/curvature_constrained_state_spaces/curvature_constrained_state_spaces_example_dubins_feasible_path_generator
/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/libcurvature_constrained_state_spaces.so: undefined reference to `nlopt_set_maxtime'
/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/libcurvature_constrained_state_spaces.so: undefined reference to `nlopt_set_xtol_abs1'
/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/libcurvature_constrained_state_spaces.so: undefined reference to `nlopt_destroy'
/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/libcurvature_constrained_state_spaces.so: undefined reference to `nlopt_set_upper_bounds'
/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/libcurvature_constrained_state_spaces.so: undefined reference to `nlopt_create'
/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/libcurvature_constrained_state_spaces.so: undefined reference to `nlopt_set_upper_bounds1'
/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/libcurvature_constrained_state_spaces.so: undefined reference to `nlopt_set_min_objective'
/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/libcurvature_constrained_state_spaces.so: undefined reference to `nlopt_set_munge'
/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/libcurvature_constrained_state_spaces.so: undefined reference to `nlopt_add_inequality_mconstraint'
/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/libcurvature_constrained_state_spaces.so: undefined reference to `nlopt_set_force_stop'
/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/libcurvature_constrained_state_spaces.so: undefined reference to `nlopt_set_lower_bounds'
/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/libcurvature_constrained_state_spaces.so: undefined reference to `nlopt_optimize'
/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/libcurvature_constrained_state_spaces.so: undefined reference to `nlopt_get_dimension'
/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/libcurvature_constrained_state_spaces.so: undefined reference to `nlopt_set_ftol_rel'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/curvature_constrained_state_spaces/curvature_constrained_state_spaces_example_bvp_solver] Error 1
make[1]: *** [curvature_constrained_state_spaces/CMakeFiles/curvature_constrained_state_spaces_example_bvp_solver.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/libcurvature_constrained_state_spaces.so: undefined reference to `nlopt_set_maxtime'
/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/libcurvature_constrained_state_spaces.so: undefined reference to `nlopt_set_xtol_abs1'
/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/libcurvature_constrained_state_spaces.so: undefined reference to `nlopt_destroy'
/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/libcurvature_constrained_state_spaces.so: undefined reference to `nlopt_set_upper_bounds'
/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/libcurvature_constrained_state_spaces.so: undefined reference to `nlopt_create'
/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/libcurvature_constrained_state_spaces.so: undefined reference to `nlopt_set_upper_bounds1'
/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/libcurvature_constrained_state_spaces.so: undefined reference to `nlopt_set_min_objective'
/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/libcurvature_constrained_state_spaces.so: undefined reference to `nlopt_set_munge'
/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/libcurvature_constrained_state_spaces.so: undefined reference to `nlopt_add_inequality_mconstraint'
/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/libcurvature_constrained_state_spaces.so: undefined reference to `nlopt_set_force_stop'
/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/libcurvature_constrained_state_spaces.so: undefined reference to `nlopt_set_lower_bounds'
/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/libcurvature_constrained_state_spaces.so: undefined reference to `nlopt_optimize'
/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/libcurvature_constrained_state_spaces.so: undefined reference to `nlopt_get_dimension'
/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/libcurvature_constrained_state_spaces.so: undefined reference to `nlopt_set_ftol_rel'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/curvature_constrained_state_spaces/curvature_constrained_state_spaces_example_distance] Error 1
make[1]: *** [curvature_constrained_state_spaces/CMakeFiles/curvature_constrained_state_spaces_example_distance.dir/all] Error 2
/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/libcurvature_constrained_state_spaces.so: undefined reference to `nlopt_set_maxtime'
/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/libcurvature_constrained_state_spaces.so: undefined reference to `nlopt_set_xtol_abs1'
/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/libcurvature_constrained_state_spaces.so: undefined reference to `nlopt_destroy'
/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/libcurvature_constrained_state_spaces.so: undefined reference to `nlopt_set_upper_bounds'
/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/libcurvature_constrained_state_spaces.so: undefined reference to `nlopt_create'
/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/libcurvature_constrained_state_spaces.so: undefined reference to `nlopt_set_upper_bounds1'
/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/libcurvature_constrained_state_spaces.so: undefined reference to `nlopt_set_min_objective'
/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/libcurvature_constrained_state_spaces.so: undefined reference to `nlopt_set_munge'
/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/libcurvature_constrained_state_spaces.so: undefined reference to `nlopt_add_inequality_mconstraint'
/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/libcurvature_constrained_state_spaces.so: undefined reference to `nlopt_set_force_stop'
/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/libcurvature_constrained_state_spaces.so: undefined reference to `nlopt_set_lower_bounds'
/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/libcurvature_constrained_state_spaces.so: undefined reference to `nlopt_optimize'
/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/libcurvature_constrained_state_spaces.so: undefined reference to `nlopt_get_dimension'
/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/libcurvature_constrained_state_spaces.so: undefined reference to `nlopt_set_ftol_rel'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/curvature_constrained_state_spaces/curvature_constrained_state_spaces_example_clothoid_path] Error 1
make[1]: *** [curvature_constrained_state_spaces/CMakeFiles/curvature_constrained_state_spaces_example_clothoid_path.dir/all] Error 2
/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/libcurvature_constrained_state_spaces.so: undefined reference to `nlopt_set_maxtime'
/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/libcurvature_constrained_state_spaces.so: undefined reference to `nlopt_set_xtol_abs1'
/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/libcurvature_constrained_state_spaces.so: undefined reference to `nlopt_destroy'
/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/libcurvature_constrained_state_spaces.so: undefined reference to `nlopt_set_upper_bounds'
/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/libcurvature_constrained_state_spaces.so: undefined reference to `nlopt_create'
/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/libcurvature_constrained_state_spaces.so: undefined reference to `nlopt_set_upper_bounds1'
/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/libcurvature_constrained_state_spaces.so: undefined reference to `nlopt_set_min_objective'
/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/libcurvature_constrained_state_spaces.so: undefined reference to `nlopt_set_munge'
/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/libcurvature_constrained_state_spaces.so: undefined reference to `nlopt_add_inequality_mconstraint'
/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/libcurvature_constrained_state_spaces.so: undefined reference to `nlopt_set_force_stop'
/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/libcurvature_constrained_state_spaces.so: undefined reference to `nlopt_set_lower_bounds'
/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/libcurvature_constrained_state_spaces.so: undefined reference to `nlopt_optimize'
/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/libcurvature_constrained_state_spaces.so: undefined reference to `nlopt_get_dimension'
/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/libcurvature_constrained_state_spaces.so: undefined reference to `nlopt_set_ftol_rel'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/alex/planner_examples_ws/devel/lib/curvature_constrained_state_spaces/curvature_constrained_state_spaces_example_dubins_feasible_path_generator] Error 1
make[1]: *** [curvature_constrained_state_spaces/CMakeFiles/curvature_constrained_state_spaces_example_dubins_feasible_path_generator.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

and the curvature_constrained_state_spaces CMakeLists.txt is following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(curvature_constrained_state_spaces)

## Find catkin macros and libraries
## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
## is used, also find other catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  ompl
  planning_common
  roscpp
  circular_curve_lib
  tictoc_profiler
  random_util
)

## System dependencies are found with CMake's conventions
# find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fPIC -std=c++11")

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})
find_package(NLopt REQUIRED)

## Uncomment this if the package has a setup.py. This macro ensures
## modules and global scripts declared therein get installed
## See http://ros.org/doc/api/catkin/html/user_guide/setup_dot_py.html
# catkin_python_setup()

################################################
## Declare ROS messages, services and actions ##
################################################

## To declare and build messages, services or actions from within this
## package, follow these steps:
## * Let MSG_DEP_SET be the set of packages whose message types you use in
##   your messages/services/actions (e.g. std_msgs, actionlib_msgs, ...).
## * In the file package.xml:
##   * add a build_depend and a run_depend tag for each package in MSG_DEP_SET
##   * If MSG_DEP_SET isn't empty the following dependencies might have been
##     pulled in transitively but can be declared for certainty nonetheless:
##     * add a build_depend tag for "message_generation"
##     * add a run_depend tag for "message_runtime"
## * In this file (CMakeLists.txt):
##   * add "message_generation" and every package in MSG_DEP_SET to
##     find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ...)
##   * add "message_runtime" and every package in MSG_DEP_SET to
##     catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS ...)
##   * uncomment the add_*_files sections below as needed
##     and list every .msg/.srv/.action file to be processed
##   * uncomment the generate_messages entry below
##   * add every package in MSG_DEP_SET to generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES ...)

## Generate messages in the 'msg' folder
# add_message_files(
#   FILES
#   Message1.msg
#   Message2.msg
# )

## Generate services in the 'srv' folder
# add_service_files(
#   FILES
#   Service1.srv
#   Service2.srv
# )

## Generate actions in the 'action' folder
# add_action_files(
#   FILES
#   Action1.action
#   Action2.action
# )

## Generate added messages and services with any dependencies listed here
# generate_messages(
#   DEPENDENCIES
#   std_msgs  # Or other packages containing msgs
# )

###################################
## catkin specific configuration ##
###################################
## The catkin_package macro generates cmake config files for your package
## Declare things to be passed to dependent projects
## INCLUDE_DIRS: uncomment this if you package contains header files
## LIBRARIES: libraries you create in this project that dependent projects also need
## CATKIN_DEPENDS: catkin_packages dependent projects also need
## DEPENDS: system dependencies of this project that dependent projects also need
catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME}
  CATKIN_DEPENDS ompl planning_common roscpp circular_curve_lib tictoc_profiler random_util
  DEPENDS NLopt
)

###########
## Build ##
###########

## Specify additional locations of header files
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations
# include_directories(include)
include_directories(
  include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

## Declare a cpp library
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} 
src/dubins_z_state_space.cpp 
src/curvature_bvp_solver.cpp 
src/clothoid_state_space.cpp 
src/dubins_feasible_path_generator.cpp 
src/clothoid_z_state_space.cpp
src/glideslope_bvp_solver.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${NLOPT_LIBRARIES})

## Declare a cpp executable
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}_example_dubins_z_path examples/example_dubins_z_path.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_example_dubins_z_path ${PROJECT_NAME} ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}_example_nlopt examples/example_nlopt.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_example_nlopt ${PROJECT_NAME} ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
# ${NLOPT_LIBRARIES}
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}_example_bvp_solver examples/example_bvp_solver.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_example_bvp_solver ${PROJECT_NAME} ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}_stress_test_bvp examples/stress_test_bvp.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_stress_test_bvp ${PROJECT_NAME} ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}_example_clothoid_path examples/example_clothoid_path.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_example_clothoid_path ${PROJECT_NAME} ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}_example_dubins_feasible_path_generator examples/example_dubins_feasible_path_generator.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_example_dubins_feasible_path_generator ${PROJECT_NAME} ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}_example_distance examples/example_distance.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_example_distance ${PROJECT_NAME} ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}_example_glideslope_bvp_solver examples/example_glideslope_bvp_solver.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_example_glideslope_bvp_solver ${PROJECT_NAME} ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

## Add cmake target dependencies of the executable/library
## as an example, message headers may need to be generated before nodes
# add_dependencies(curvature_constrained_state_spaces_node curvature_constrained_state_spaces_generate_messages_cpp)

## Specify libraries to link a library or executable target against
# target_link_libraries(curvature_constrained_state_spaces_node
#   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
# )

#############
## Install ##
#############

# all install targets should use catkin DESTINATION variables
# See http://ros.org/doc/api/catkin/html/adv_user_guide/variables.html

## Mark executable scripts (Python etc.) for installation
## in contrast to setup.py, you can choose the destination
# install(PROGRAMS
#   scripts/my_python_script
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
# )

IF ("${ACS_INSTALL_TYPE}" STREQUAL "FULL")

## Mark executables and/or libraries for installation
 install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
   ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
   LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
   RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
 )

## Mark cpp header files for installation
 install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
   FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
   PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE
 )

ENDIF()

## Mark other files for installation (e.g. launch and bag files, etc.)
# install(FILES
#   # myfile1
#   # myfile2
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}
# )

#############
## Testing ##
#############

## Add gtest based cpp test target and link libraries
# catkin_add_gtest(${PROJECT_NAME}-test test/test_curvature_constrained_state_spaces.cpp)
# if(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}-test)
#   target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}-test ${PROJECT_NAME})
# endif()

## Add folders to be run by python nosetests
# catkin_add_nosetests(test)
```

i found a findnlopt.cmake in the CMAKE file, seems the writer happen the same problem somtime, but i don't know how to use it.
it's like this:

```
# - Find NLopt
# Find the native NLopt includes and library
#
# NLOPT_INCLUDE_DIR - where to find nlopt.h, etc.
# NLOPT_LIBRARIES - List of libraries when using nlopt.
# NLOPT_FOUND - True if nlopt found.


IF (NLOPT_INCLUDE_DIR)
# Already in cache, be silent
SET (nlopt_FIND_QUIETLY TRUE)
ENDIF (NLOPT_INCLUDE_DIR)

FIND_PATH(NLOPT_INCLUDE_DIR nlopt.h)

SET (NLOPT_NAMES nlopt nlopt_cxx)
FIND_LIBRARY (NLOPT_LIBRARY NAMES ${NLOPT_NAMES})

# handle the QUIETLY and REQUIRED arguments and set NLOPT_FOUND to TRUE if
# all listed variables are TRUE
INCLUDE (FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS (NLOPT DEFAULT_MSG
NLOPT_LIBRARY
NLOPT_INCLUDE_DIR)

IF(NLOPT_FOUND)
SET (NLOPT_LIBRARIES ${NLOPT_LIBRARY})
ELSE (NLOPT_FOUND)
SET (NLOPT_LIBRARIES)
ENDIF (NLOPT_FOUND)

MARK_AS_ADVANCED (NLOPT_LIBRARY NLOPT_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248073/undefined-reference-to-nlopt/) by [rchml](https://answers.ros.org/users/28527/rchml/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2016-11-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-14**:
Please use the *Preformatted Text* button (the one with `101010` on it) next time when copying console text into your question. It makes things much easier to read. Thanks.

**Comment by [rchml](https://answers.ros.org/users/28527/rchml/) on 2016-11-14**:
ok, i'm sorry, first time to make a question.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2016-11-14**:
This is most likely an issue with your CMakeLists.txt. Please update question and add that file. I haven't used nlopt much, but I was able to compile an example I had lying around with CMake by specifically appending path to SO file like the following:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

oh, let me end my problem.(get help from labmate)
int the cmakelists.txt , focus on the last line. the `project_name`means my findnlopt.cmake works no results. you can change it with `${NLOPT_LIBRARIES}` now, it works well.
or in the terminal:
5.`catkin_make clean` and. `rm -Rf devel/ build/`

which also works. it's just a demo to show the related problems.
thanks upfloor guy.

```
 ## Declare a cpp library
    add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} 
    src/dubins_z_state_space.cpp 
    src/curvature_bvp_solver.cpp 
    src/clothoid_state_space.cpp 
    src/dubins_feasible_path_generator.cpp 
    src/clothoid_z_state_space.cpp
    src/glideslope_bvp_solver.cpp)
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${NLOPT_LIBRARIES})
    
    ## Declare a cpp executable
    add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}_example_dubins_z_path examples/example_dubins_z_path.cpp)
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_example_dubins_z_path ${PROJECT_NAME} ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

---

Originally posted by [rchml](https://answers.ros.org/users/28527/rchml/) with karma: 16 on 2016-11-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On my system, the `nlopt` version from apt-get has its headers and libs automatically installed to directories where CMake can find them. Therefore I can get away without using `find_package` at all and instead directly use `target_link_libraries`. This isn't very portable, but it will likely solve your issue. In general, you'd likely be better off writing a `FindNLOPT.cmake` file, but this might also require writing a `NLOPTConfig.cmake` file (I'm no expert on writing those files, but it seems complicated to get versions that work well on all systems). The following CMakeLists.txt file builds a simple nlopt demo for me.

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)

project(nlopt_test)

add_executable(demo example.cpp)
target_link_libraries(demo nlopt)
```

Perhaps that will help you sort out your errors.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2016-11-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rchml](https://answers.ros.org/users/28527/rchml/) on 2016-11-15**:
thank you very much, i update the CMakeLists.txt.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2016-11-15**:
Thanks for converting this to an answer.... I went ahead and edited it to make it more useful as an answer.

**Comment by [rchml](https://answers.ros.org/users/28527/rchml/) on 2016-11-17**:
i found a findnlopt.cmake file, but do not know how to use it. maybe i should to contact to the project writer.

**Comment by [Rocknz](https://answers.ros.org/users/28974/rocknz/) on 2018-11-14**:
Thanks! It really works!